# WHM Debug Email Sending Issue

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a WHM server - with several PHP scripts on it that send off emails.  It used to work until apparently just recently.  Now, it seems to have stopped sending emails from those scripts.

Given that I know there's no problem with the scripts themselves, how would I go about debugging why they're no longer being sent?

Here's what I know so far:

1. PHP Scripts should be fine, nothing has changed on them
2. Server does not appear on any spam blacklists
3. Test email script does not generate any errors, nor is there anything hung up in the WHM queue
4. Nothing shows up in the gmail accounts (regular or spam boxes) for what's supposed to have been sent.

Any ideas?

WHM 60 Build 35, CentOS 6

Comment: can you please post your php form code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to follow the instructions bellow which could help you in debbuging your email issue(s):

```
1) - check if you server has a valid hostname like host.domain.tld and that hostname actually points to the server's ip address
2) - check if you have rDNS setup correctly for your server's ip address and the reverse DNS should match the hostname
3) - Use Mail Queue Manager from WHM (in the left search in WHM got o Email -> Mail Queue Manager) and see if there are any emails in the mail queue there
4) - Use Mail Troubleshooter from WHM ( Email -> Mail Troubleshooter) and see what happens when you try to send an email to a gmail address
5) - You could check the Exim server logs by logging in via ssh and do a tail -f /var/log/exim_mainlog
```

Most probably your emails are in the server's mail queue and for some reason they are not delivered